How do i stop packet flooding on my server?
I use a debian server to host my site, but i've found about this vulnerability in it that it could receive half the packets in a packet flood with this command,
ping -s <size of packet in bytes> -f <server ip or domain>

how can i block this?

To prevent TCP/IP packets from reaching a server you need to either unplug the server OR block such packets further upstream, in the network of your provider for example. A host based firewall can mitigate the issue somewhat by preventing your system from having to respond to unwanted traffic, but that unwanted traffic is still reaching the server and can still congest your uplink.
